# Error while starting web application

Tags: iis

When you right-click a Web site in the Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in, and then you click Start, the Web site does not start and you receive the following error message:

**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

What have to do.

To resolve this issue i got this solution: 
You must use the Netstat.exe utility at the command line to see if another process is using port 80 or port 443.

But how to ensure that is these Ip are in use or not ? in terms of status ? What should its status ?

Second solution is : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\ListenOnlyList. 
But this key is not found .

Comment: Recommend move to ServerFault

Comment: Do you have more than one website?  If so, check your website bindings and specify a host header in the one that is giving you problems.  Or - move your new site into a virtual directory of your main site.  Either way, you have more than one site listening on port 80 right now without specifying host headers.

Comment: where have to check this host header ? and can modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i keep error as it is and I reinstall IIS and required software.

Answer (score 1):

Lalit, this should probably be on ServerFault.com as this is more of a server administration question.  With that said, you probably have more than one website listening on port 80 or 443 without the use of host headers.  When using port 80, you cannot have more than one site on the port without specifying the domain name(s) to use in your website bindings.  443 (HTTPS) gets a little more tricky as you typically cannot have more than one site use 443 even if you are using host headers (there are exceptions like wildcard SSL certs).  This is due to IIS not being able to read the host headers and know which SSL cert to use to decrypt them since they are encrypted.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890015  for more information

More links:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308163

[Google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=iis+host+header&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=iis+host+hea&gs_rfai=CC8kEGC0OTKWdM4uugATnu7y-CgAAAKoEBU_Q-xNE&fp=927f32381456711a)